# Dropdown list issues

Tags: python, html, mysql, jinja2

I've also been trying to set a default value in a dropdown box on HTML from the data I retrieved from MySQL.

However, I noticed that if the user did not click on the dropdown box and clicked on one item from it. In other words, if they assumed the displayed value is the value they would like to submit (even though this is simply for displaying purpose and this is no value). The website would default as the value is none and can't be added to the MySQL database.

Therefore, I'm wondering is there a way to force users must click on the dropdown box and choose one from the list?

```
    <select name="plan" id="plan" required>
    <option value="{{database[1]}}" selected disabled hidden>{{database[1]}}</option>
    {% for result in database2 %}
    <option value={{result[0]}}>{{result[0]}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `required` attribute and make the first options a prompt to select. If the value is blank, the form cannot be submitted

```
<select name="plan" id="plan" required>
  <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
```

Comment: can't believe it's that simple. I did use the required but didn't realise that the none is not that none. Btw, do you mind if you can take a look at the first part of my question? thanks

Comment: Can you please split the questions. Select and cut the first part and make a new PHP question

Comment: don't know why they wouldn't let me to post

Comment: Managed to do that. Here;'s the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72515883/dropdown-list-for-loop-replacement